# How to do a hardware level check for Anisotropic filtering support?

Tags: c++

I just finished implementing Anisotropic filtering support in my game, but I'm not quite sure how to do a hardware level check to see if the user hardware supports the method. Is there a way to use CheckDeviceFormat to see if the hardware supports it, or does the device automatically default to trilinear if the hardware doesn't support anisotropic filtering? Thanks in advance :)

Update: new problem, I just did some more tests to confirm if x16 af is being used, apparently it's not, it's just a x1 af. maybe I'm missing something? I applied the samplerstates and set the maxanisotropy to be 16.  Here's the code showing How I'm setting the sampler state:

```
        // 0 = textures
        pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC);
        pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState( 0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER , D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC);
        pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, bTrilinear ? D3DTEXF_LINEAR : D3DTEXF_NONE);
        pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAXANISOTROPY, 16);

        // 1 = lightmaps
        pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(1, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC);
        pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState( 1, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER , D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC);
        pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(1, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, bTrilinear ? D3DTEXF_LINEAR : D3DTEXF_NONE);
        pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(1, D3DSAMP_MAXANISOTROPY, 16);
```

Update 2: 
This picture shows the amount of blurriness that occurs the further out you are from the camera:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Q6ap1zZ.png]

Comment: well, what are you working with? A graphics API? Which one?

Comment: Oh sorry about that pfann I completely forgot to mention that didn't I. Working with directx.

Comment: I think you should be able to retrieve the info through IDirect3D9::GetDeviceCaps. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. You'll get a D3DCAPS9 struct, which among other pieces of information, contains the TextureFilterCaps(Caps is short for capabilities) and also MaxAnisotropy

Comment: Just did more tests to see if my af was really x16 and it's only 1x, even with maxanisotropy set to 16. any idea what would be causing that?

Comment: Well, my second issue is posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics library should have implemented a function like:

```
magic::supports(magic::anistropic_filtering)     //say magic is the name of your library
```

which returns a bool with the obvious meaning.

Depends on your graphics library, though.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to implement a check using d3dcaps9, but I was wondering if you happened to know how to achieve x16 anisotropic filtering? Currently only x1 is being used even though I set the maximum samples to be 16, and used a log to confirm that the hardware supports 16 samples.

Comment: @Jeff My directX knowledge is really, really limited, so i don't have an answer for that.

Comment: @Jeff could you please extend your question with some more information. For example, the code in which you set the sampler filtering etc.

Answer (score 0):

So as I posted before, you can check the hardware capabilities of a D3D device by calling IDirect3D9::GetDeviceCaps(). You need to pass apointer to a D3DCAPS9 struct, which will then be filled with the information gathered. Among the pieces of information is "TextureFilterCaps" and "MaxAnisotropy" which can tell yout if and how well anisotropic filtering is supported.

As for your second issue, I'm not sure but I think you also have to set D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER to D3DTEXF_ANISOTROPIC to get it working.

How are you testing which which degree of isotropy is used?

Comment: I did try both caps.MaxAnisotropy & just filling it in with the actual value i wanted. I also used a log to make sure my gpu supports af at x16, which it does according to my log. Afaik d3dtexf_anisotropic on the mipfilter is an invalid combination. It's like the gpu recognizes I want x16 filtering set but isnt applying it.

Comment: @Jeff you mean setting the MAxAnisotropy of the D3DCAPS9 struct you get?

Comment: Correct, the log revealed my gpu does support a setting of 16 samples, it's just not applying it.

Comment: @Jeff you can't set the values in the D3DCAPS9 struct, that has no effect, since it just is a return value of what your HW is capable of with D3D. If it says only MaxAF 1 is supported then you're stuck with that.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well, but my log revealed my gpu does support 16 as a max AF value, it's just not being set. Code example.
log("Maximum supported AF samples: %d \n", caps.MaxAnisotropy);
here's the output I received:
Maximum supported AF samples: 16

Comment: @Jeff I think I just mis-read your comment. How do you check what your sampler uses for filtering? Tbh, the small image you posted looks fine to me, on the other hand it's kinda tiny to really see what's going on.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to check what sampling level is being applied, I've just been guessing that it's around 2x. I was able to clean the image up slightly by toying with the LOD though, it's much clearer now but still not x16